# I don't want to click a entry field to input the data.Is is able to do that?

Tags: python, html, flask

I've been making the simple quiz app with Flask.

The overview of it is very simple.

Each question,input field,submission button are displayed.

So I don't want to let player click the input field each time to input the answer.

Below code display the question,input field,submission button.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

<form action="{{url_for('judge',id=answer) }}" method=post>

    <li>{{question}}<input type="text"class="form- 
control"id="InputTitle"name="answer"size="5.5px" autocomplete="off">

        <button type="submit"class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </li>
   </form>
</ul>
{%endblock%}
```

How do I implement it?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [`autofocus` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp)

If you add this to your input field, it should get the keyboard focus when the page loads:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputTitle"
     name="answer" size="5.5px" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
```